The origin of "concave up" and "concave down"
The terms "concave up" and "concave down" seem to only appear in introductory calculus textbooks written for freshmen college students in USA. Elsewhere in mathematics, we don't use such terms.
I wonder where and when these terms were introduced and why. Especially since we have a perfectly good and much more entrenched word: Convex.

I do not know, but my guess would be that some old Calculus book author did it (perhaps because their students had trouble keeping "convex"/"concave" straight) and it has been perpetuated forward.

I suspect @StevenGubkin is right. I suppose you could try asking over on History of Science and Mathematics.

Personally, I find concave a much more transparent word than convex. I like the terms. (And I don't know anything about their history.)

@SueVanHattum: Now I'm curious why you find concave more transparent than convex - and more importantly, why you find "concave up" and "concave down" transparent. The choice of up and down seems completely arbitrary to me - and even worse, a function is "concave down", if and only if the region below its graph is convex, while it is "concave up" if and only if the region above its graph is convex.

@JochenGlueck, the caved in part faces up for concave up, and down for concave down.

It doesn't help that a an object (like a wall or a hillside) that has caved in would be concave out. I find these words as confucing as non-increasing and non-decreasing.

@Arthur: we are talking about graphs of functions, which cannot look like caves in a hill

@JochenGlueck with convex/concave you need some mnemonic aid to remember which is which (how do you do it?), with concave up and concave down you need that less.

@SueVanHattum: Thanks for your reply! Ah ok, I see how this can work in English (in doesn't in my native language German, which explains my question). I still share Arthur's concern, though, that one might quite reasonably interpret the words in just the opposite way.

@MichaelBächtold: "how do you do it?" I think about sets rather than functions: I find the notion of a convex set quite intuitive (maybe also because one rarely speaks of concave sets), and a convex function is simply a function whose epigraph is convex. (Admittedly, this leaves the question why one considers the epigraph rather than the region below the graph - for some reason I never found this difficult to remember, though.)

@JochenGlueck and this is almost meaningless to me (MA in math, but poor memory) and certainly meaningless to calc I students.

@SueVanHattum: Yes, I agree that this appoach might not reach its full potential in a calculus 1 class. Why would it be meaningless to the students there, though? One can explain it in a straightforward way: "When is a lense convex? If the straight line between any two points on the surface does not leave the lense anywhere. When is a function convex? If the aforementioned condition is true for the region above the function's graph. So if you connect two points on the graph by a straight line, the line has to be located above the graph." [...]

[...] Coming back to the beginning of the discussion: I think I would not be able to remember the definition of a convex function without this geometric picture in mind. I could probably still remember the distinction between convex and concave functions (by keeping some standard examples of convex functions in mind, say $x \mapsto x^2$ or $\exp$), but if I have to write down the actual definition of a convex function, then how to do it without thinking about straight lines between points on the graph?

Afterthought: Maybe we focus on different view points though? If one focusses on sufficiently smooth functions and introduces convex and concave functions in terms of the second derivative, then I understand that the description of convexity in terms of the epigraph is not of much help. If one also wants to treat non-smooth functions (which I personally find preferrable for a number of reasons) and thus defines convexity in terms of an inequality for convex combinations, then thinking about it in terms of the epigraph seems the most intuitive apprach to me.

A cute trick that I once heard to remember the convex and concave distinction when discussing functions: the function $e^x$ is conv$e^x$!

The terms "concave up/down" describe shapes of graphs in basic calculus courses in US English, where you never encounter "convex up/down". The situation is reversed in Russian, where the standard labels in this setting are convex down (выпуклый вниз) and convex up (выпуклый вверх). Using the 2nd derivative,  where $f'' > 0$ we use in US English the term "concave up" and where $f'' < 0$ we use the term "concave down", while in Russian $f'' > 0$ is called convex down and $f'' < 0$ is called convex up. I don't know how this works in other languages.

The notion of a curve being concave in some direction is not newer than the modern notion of a convex function.  Here is how the terminology of concavity has developed over the centuries. We can start at least as early as L’Hôpital’s Analyse des Infiniment Petits in 1696.

Lorsqu’une ligne courbe AFK est en partie concave et en partie convexe vers une ligne droite AB ou vers un point fixe B; le point F qui sépare la partie concave de la convexe, et qui par conséquent est la fin de l’une et la commencement de l’autre, est appellé point d’infléxion…

Early on, authors wrote that curves were concave towards or convex towards a line or point. In English for example, this is from Introduction to the Doctrine of Fluxions by John Rowe in 1751.

When a Curve from being Concave becomes Convex towards its Axis, or from being Convex becomes Concave, that Point where the Change is made, or that which separates the Convex from the Concave Part, is called the Point of Inflection…

At some point, English authors started using the terminology of curves being concave or convex upwards or downwards.
For example in John Hind’s 1831 The Principles of the Differential Calculus, he first uses the terms convex towards the x-axis and concave towards the x-axis in his section the direction of curvature. But when he discusses the example of the right strophoid, he writes that “the symmetrical branches are respectively concave upwards and downwards.”
In Edward Albert Bowser’s 1885 An Elementary Treatise on the Differential and Integral Calculus, he begins the section on direction of curvature by discussing a curve being concave or convex towards the x-axis, but then immediately begins discussing the notions of concave and convex downwards.

If a curve is concave downwards… the derivative of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ or $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ is negative.
In the same way if the curve is convex downwards… the derivative of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ or $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ is positive.

In The Elements of the Differential and Integral Calculus by Donald Francis Campbell in 1904, Campbell introduces the terms “concave upwards” and “concave downwards” in relation to slopes of tangent lines increasing or decreasing. He never uses the word convex to describe a curve. Within a few years, many textbooks were abbreviating the terms to “concave up” and “concave down.”
Typical calculus textbooks used in the United States have not deeply changed since the early to mid 1900s. The presentation has changed, but the substance is largely the same.
I am not as familiar with textbooks used at a similar level in other countries. From my limited knowledge, I have a hypothesis that I currently don’t have time to research. I believe the modern study of convexity and convex functions emerged more recently and at a relatively more advanced level than the notion of curves being concave in some direction. This idea made its way into analysis textbooks both in the U.S. and elsewhere, but U.S. calculus textbooks calcified before this.

Perhaps the origin can be traced to Newton's Bucket. There is a good Wikipedia article, and the article Newton’s Rotating Water Bucket: A Simple Model by Mungan and Lipscome is readable.
Newton writes about a bucket that holds water, suspended by a cord. The cord is twisted and then the bucket is released so that it can spin. The profile of the surface of the spinning mass of water develops into a parabolic shape. Newton of course wrote in Latin, but translations use the word concave to describe this shape. In the nomenclature of modern calculus textbooks, this shape would be classified as "concave up."
